# How to Bind Event comboBox -TextBox

Tags: c#, event-handling, dynamic-controls

İ have a calculation about something and create a form  dynamiclly as this.

```
 comboboxAdet.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 300);
            comboboxAdet.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(515, 5);
            comboboxAdet.Margin = new Padding(2, 3, 2, 3);
            comboboxAdet.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(combobox_SelectedindexChanged);
            /**************************************************/
            TextBox textSatirtoplam = new TextBox();
            textSatirtoplam.Text = satirhesapla(i);
            textSatirtoplam.Name = "labelSatirToplam" + i.ToString();
            textSatirtoplam.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 300);
            textSatirtoplam.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(630, 5);
            textSatirtoplam.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(combobox_SelectedindexChanged);
            textSatirtoplam.Visible = true;
```

problem is how to when i change comboxBoxSelected item , textbox can change. i tried eventhandler but get fail. that means how to reach textbox?

[image]

if you help me ,i will be really happy! Thanks
i hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you want to update the text box on the same row as on which the `SelectIndexChanged` event occurred.

You can use a delegate and passing a closure to your event to obtain a reference to text box.

```
var combox = new ComboBox();
// code left out

var txtBox = new TextBox();
// code left out

combox.SelectedIndexChanged += delegate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var destTextBox = txtBox;  // important assign closure to a local variable.
    var srcCombo = (ComboBox) sender;

    destTextBox.Text = srcCombo.SelectedText;
};
```

Comment: thanks for response. İ couldnt tell what i want sorry for that, i solve my problem with finding all controls in a form and finding a specific control item. Thanks again.